# Node.js - external middleware causing 404

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a simple express app (version 4.9.0) and I am trying to put my middleware in to external files.

My app.js has:

`var middleware = require('./lib/middleware');
app.get('/foo', middleware.configcache);`

/lib/middleware contains index.js:

`exports.configcache = require('./configcache.js');`

/lib/middleware/configcache.js contains:

```
function configcache(req, res, next) {
  console.log("hello world");
  next();
}

module.exports = configcache;
```

When I make a GET request to /foo I get a 404. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I use it in one of my apps:

*app.js:*

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
```

*routes/index.js:*

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: req.i18n.t("meta.title.index")
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I scaffolded this express project with the [yeoman](http://yeoman.io) [express generator](https://github.com/petecoop/generator-express): `yo express`

**So the answer to your problem is:** Don't call next(), but send an actual response to the browser - when you are using router.get():

```
function configcache(req, res, next) {
    res.send(200, 'hello world');
}
```

or use router.use like described here: http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html